# How would you invent the word for 'fear of standing next to beds'?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, suffixes, phobias

It is known that there is a proper word for almost any phobia you can think of. What is the etymology of such? And how would one construct the word for the phobia of standing next to beds; because of what may be lurking underneath to grab your ankles.

I know, this is ridiculously specific, but this is just for a bit of fun, I know that many people at some point in their lives have shared this fear.

Comment: Well, start by finding Latin and Greek terms for "fear", "bed", and "next to".  Combine them in random ways until it sounds good.  (And the monster under you bed is named Arnie, and he's a nice monster.)

Comment: I don't think such a fear as we have all shared counts as a phobia, they are supposed to be more debilitating than that. If you can't ever get into bed, then yes.

Comment: Actually, it's strange there isn't a term for **fear of things lurking under beds**.  Because that is very common.  (Extremely specific variants of this .. fear of things lurking under bed while in bed, inability to get up to go to restroom due to fear of things lurking under bed, fear of things lurking under bed when standing beside a bed ... I don't care about that. But you'd think there would be a word for "fear of things lurking under bed" since it's so common!)  As common as "fear of the dark".

Comment: Norwegian has a word _lakenskrek_ or "terror of bedsheets", but it's used, not for a phobia, but for the unwillingness of small children to go to bed. This is an acute problem in the light summer nights, when the sun is up for hours after their bedtime! And an adult friend self-identifies, I think some people are actually on a 27-hour day. Anyway, a word we should have in English too.

Comment: @HotLicks , I took the latin route in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semi-latinate version is "Juxta-Stantem-Cubilibus-O-Phobia" ; Shorten it to "JuxtaCubilibusOPhobia".
Further shorten it to **"JuxtaCubilibOPhobia" or "JuxtaCubilOPhobia"**.

**English "standing next to beds" == latin "juxta se stantem cubilibus".**

Comment: Juxtacubilibusophobia, I like it! Might wait and see for other answers to come in.

Comment: For this matter, it might be nice to shorten it to juxtacubilibophobia removing the 'us' from the middle, rolls off the tongue nicer; I think.

Comment: @SamWalls , Done. After removal of "ib", it still makes some "sense" as Juxta(=next-to)Cubil(=bed?)OPhobia. Can we further shorten it ?

Answer (score 6):

For a bit of fun..

**-phobia**    is the ending for most of the fear words

**-krebbato-**   old Greek or **-krebeto-** modern will do for bed. Then if you like add...

**hypo-** means under, **ana-** means against **para-** means beside. Pick one. ***Anacrebetophobia***

Or you could pick a crawly monster:  ***Echidnophobia***   (three hits on Google)

Another Greek word for bed is **Klino-**, and there is a real word ***Clinophobia***, for an illness; it depends how serious you want to be about fear of going to bed.

Comment: [_Krabbatos_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/κράββατος) means more ___couch___ than _bed_. I think [___kline___](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/κλίνη) is best used for meaning _bed_, as in _clinephobia_.

Comment: Well, this gives us (taking on board the comments by zenith): paraklinophobia and hypoklinophobia for the fears of 'beside bed' and 'under bed' respectively. I might try to incorporate standing in the words to give them more meaning.